# float to integer in csv.writer python

Tags: python, csv, matrix

I have different files (at least 10) with a 34x34 matrix and i sum each file into a single 34x34 matrix. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np 
import os
import glob


a = np.zeros((34,34))
os.chdir("\dir\folder")     
events = glob.glob("*.txt")     

for file in events:
    d = np.loadtxt(file,delimiter=' ',dtype=int)
    a = a + d    
    path = "TotalEvents"

if not os.path.exists(path):                        
    os.makedirs(path, 0777)

SumMat = "TotalEvents" + ".txt"                         
with open(os.path.join("TotalEvents",SumMat), 'wb') as outfile: 
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(a)                         

outfile.close()
```

The code creates a folder in the direction of the original files, but the resulting file gives me the values in floats and i need integers.

Comment: What does it give you exactly? If possible post a working minimal example so that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `os.chdir("C:\dir\folder")`?

Comment: you shouldn't use `file` as a variable name, you're shadowing a built in.

Comment: You *accumulation* is named ```a``` but you are writing something named ```d```.

Comment: @syntonym it gives me the matrix zeros((34,34)) in float not int

Comment: @will: While I generally agree about shadowing built-ins, when was the last time you used `file`?

Comment: @martineau - i know. It has the same arguments as `open`, which is nearly always the appropriate function to use. There are only two reasons I would avoid it, the functional reason is `isinstance(f, file)`, although i admit this is pretty rarely used; the main reason i avoid it is because syntax highlighting editors pick up `file` and so it can be misleading when scanning back through the code.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: It should probably be `os.chdir(r"C:\dir\folder")` (or simply `os.chdir("C:/dir/folder")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `a = np.zeros((34,34))` to `a = np.zeros((34,34), dtype=int)`